# OCaml syntax error in type declaration

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to OCaml and I have no clue why this is giving me a syntax error:

```
type ('nonterminal, 'terminal) pe =
| Empty
| T of t 
| N of n
| Seq of list
| Choose of list
| Star of e
| Not of e;;

type ('nonterminal, 'terminal) pe_tree = 
| Is_empty 
| Leaf of t 
| Node of (n,tree) 
| Sequence of list 
| Repeat of list 
| Is_not of e;;
```

All it's saying is that there's a syntax error on line 14 characters 0-1 (which is where `| Sequence of list` is) and I can't figure out why!

Answer (score 8):

```
type ('nonterminal, 'terminal) pe_tree = 
  | Is_empty 
  | Leaf of t 
  | Node of (n * tree) 
  | Sequence of list 
  | Repeat of list 
  | Is_not of e;;
```

You use `*` to define product types, as in `'a * 'b`. Although probably not too important now, you should know that `Node of 'a * 'b` and `Node of ('a * 'b)` are different. You can think of them as a variant type with two parameters, and the other a variant type with one parameter (a tuple), respectively.

There are a few other things,

- you need to define what `Sequence` and `Repeat` are a list of.
- `'nonterminal` and `'terminal` aren't used; unless they are for phantom types, which i doubt it, they probably should be used in part of the signature.

Comment: Thank you! I'm confused though, because I have another type declaration before it (which I just added in to my original question) and it's compiling just fine :/

Comment: there has to be more then just those type definitions; `t`, `e` are not defined, along with the other things I've mentioned. Neither of those definitions should compile as you've displayed them.

Comment: Ohh ok, I see. It's obvious now haha I don't know why I was having so much trouble - thank you!